# AngularJS: element.show() in directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive ([see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GiityBz2oOrWxP8gjTgZ?p=preview)) that wraps a DIV with style `display:none` and after one second shows its content. I tried to make it display with element.show() and $(element).show() (including jQuery) but it never worked. The timeout works, what's wrong with this code?

This is the HTML:

```
    <hideme>
      Show this after one second
    </hideme>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
angular.module("app", []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {}

angular.module("app").directive('hideme', function($timeout) {

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div style="display: none !important"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            $timeout(function() {
                  element.show();
            }, 1000);
        }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bzhCwjXdll3ibxc7qsMY?p=preview

Try using `transclude:true` and then `ng-transclude` to display the markup between custom element tags. Also, I'm not familiar with using `show()`, so instead set html `ng-show='showEl'` and define `showEl = true` in the timeout.

```
angular.module("app", []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {}

angular.module("app").directive('hideme', function($timeout) {

    return {
          transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-show="showEl"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            $timeout(function() {
                  scope.showEl = true;
              }, 1000);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: sorry, not working, this is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JeQz5Ab35zuKoi2k9tCF?p=preview)

Comment: Seems like the cdn that plnkr uses isn't grabbing angular. Check the plunk, works after subbing in cdnjs resource .. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js

Comment: by using a scope variable to check wether we have to display it or not, it require a variable by element. in my case i would have a link to show details per each messages generated by a ng-repeat directive. if I click a button every details of every messages will show up :/

Comment: Alex, would you make a plunk to show me what you mean? Sounds like you might add ng-if="" on the ng-repeat element..

Answer (score 4):

The element is shown, the problem is that it does not contain anything to show. Also, to have the show function, you need to add a jQuery dependency and apply it to the correct div.

```js
angular.module("app", []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {}

angular.module("app").directive('hideme', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div style="display: none;"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.find("div:hidden").show();
      }, 1000)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <hideme>
    Show me after one second.
  </hideme>
</div>
```

That said. I would do it this way:

```js
angular.module("app", []).directive('hideme', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<div ng-show="show"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.show = false;
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.show = true;
      }, 1000)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <hideme>
    Show me after one second.
  </hideme>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **The template gets inserted into your custom tag, so your `<div>` becomes a child of the `<hideme>` tag.**
2. **In the link() function, the `element` argument is the `<hideme>` tag--not the `<div>`--therefore unhiding the `<hideme>` tag does not unhide a child `<div>` which has been styled with `display: none`. In other words, if you have this:**

   `<hideme style="display: block">
     <div style="display: none">Show this in three seconds.</div>
   </hideme>`

   **that won't  display the `<div>`.**
3. **If you don't load jQuery before loading angularjs, then angularjs uses something it calls jqLite to wrap elements.  The wrapped elements act like jQuery wrapped sets, but they have reduced functionality, e.g. show() and hide() are not provided.**

So if you load jQuery and then load angularjs, you can do this:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('hideMe', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  var directive = {};

  directive.restrict = 'E';

  directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(
      '<div style="display:none">' 
      + element.text() 
      + '</div>'
    );

    $timeout(function() {
      element.children().show();
    }, 3000);

  };


  return directive;
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <!-- For html5 (default is UTF-8) -->
  <meta charaset="UTF-8">
  <!-- For Bootstrap -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>AngularJS Examples</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- app.css -->
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="container">

   <hide-me>Show this after three seconds.</hide-me>



<!-- JQuery 2.1.1 -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular 1.3.3 -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- app.js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I notice that the text flashes briefly on the page before being hidden. **Edit:** If I replace `element.text()` with `element.html()`, then there's no flash.

On the other hand, if you don't load jQuery you can do this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('hideMe', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  var directive = {};

  directive.restrict = 'E';

  directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var hideme = element[0];
    hideme.innerHTML = '<div style="display:none">' + hideme.innerHTML + '</div>';

    $timeout(function() {
      var div = hideme.childNodes[0];
      div.style.display = "block";
    }, 3000);

  };


  return directive;
}]);
```

Then the text doesn't flash on the screen before being hidden.

Answer (score 3):

.hide() and .show() functions work only if jquery is inserted before angular in your html file.

Gwenn

Comment: This answer says the same thing as point #3 in my answer--and 3 months after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily just use the following without including jQuery to show the element:

```
element.css('display', 'block');
```

And corresponding to hide it:

```
element.css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't think people realize that ng-hide and ng-show don't always work for the situation you're in.